# PHP checkbox form retrieval, tried all stackoverflow solutions

Tags: php, html, checkbox

```
<table>
                            <col width="250">
                            <col width="250">
                            <col width="250">
                            <tr><td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Pepperoni<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Mushroom<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Bacon
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Onion<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Tomatoes<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Olives
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Pineapple<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Green Pepper<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]"/>Extra Cheese
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

$toppings = isset($_POST["toppings[]"]) ? $_POST["toppings[]"] : array("");
foreach($toppings as $chk => $selection){
    echo $selection . ", ";
}
```

/*
    For what ever reason my $selection value is always empty. The most I have ever gotten to print was the word "on" which would only be on if at least one of the checkboxes were checked off. I have attempted over 30 different solutions to iterating through checkbox arrays, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sorry for the poorly formatted code, and thanks in advance for the help.
```

*/

Comment: You might want to give your checkboxes a _value_ …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the `value=` attribute to your checkboxes

```
<tr><td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Pepperoni" />Pepperoni<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Mushroom"/>Mushroom<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Bacon" />Bacon
</td>

<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Onion" />Onion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Tomatoes" />Tomatoes<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Olives" />Olives
</td>

<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Pinapple" />Pineapple<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Green Pepper" />Green Pepper<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Extra Cheese" />Extra Cheese
</td></tr>
```

and check `$_POST["toppings"]`, not `$_POST["toppings[]"]`

```
$toppings = isset($_POST["toppings"]) ? $_POST["toppings"] : array();
if(!empty($toppings)){
   foreach($toppings as $chk => $selection){
        echo $selection . ", ";
   }
```

Comment: There is no value for any checkboxes

Comment: I have tried exactly as suggested Sean (By the way thanks for the responses everyone, I noticed the value issue and adjusted it also.) Unless I have $_POST["toppings[]"] with the square brackets, when I try and use $toppings in the foreach() I get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...

Comment: DO a var_dump( $_POST ) to see what values and names are being sent through to your page.

Comment: At this point, I can cast the $toppings in the foreach like so,
foreach((array)$toppings as $chk => $selection){

}
When I do this, its displaying just "on" again, and not any of the values.

Comment: `$_POST["toppings[]"]` is incorrect syntax. Your values are like `$_POST["toppings"][]` not `$_POST["toppings[]"]`

Comment: When I var_dump after the follwoing: $toppings = isset($_POST["toppings"]) ? $_POST["toppings"] : array();
var_dump($toppings); it spits out "string(2) "on"". At this point I have assigned values to each checkbox.

Comment: `$toppings` is casting to a string -> `string(2)`. So check your html code as it appears you might have another checkbox named `name=toppings` after these checkboxes, which is overwriting all the checkboxes named `name=toppings[]`

Comment: I have been through each line of my code over and over again. Nothing that would suggest the a `name=toppings` might have slipped in there. When I var_dump having NOTHING selected, the following line is spit out. array(0) { }. If anything is selected it goes back to string(2).

Comment: So there is no doubt, that when I am assing `$toppings = isset($_POST["toppings"]) ? $_POST["toppings"] : array();` It is doing so in an array format, but it is simply assigning the word "on", if I print out $toppings[0] it comes up with "o" and $toppings[1] comes up with "n". I am positive I do not have any other checkboxes set as `name=toppings` but still it seems like the values are not getting passed on, according to a number of responses to the word 'on' being spit out.

Comment: Try dumping `$_POST` -> `var_dump( $_POST )`. Put it before where you are assigning `$toppings`

Comment: If i just dump $_POST it displays everything that I had used $_POST on before to retrieve text fields, and a radio button. I made a test php with a very simple html code with 3 checkboxes, and its working, pulling the values as expected. I guess that means somewhere something is amiss with my code, just unfortunately after this many times of re-reading my code, I cannot find where my error is...

Comment: What is the name of the radio button? Is it also `toppings`? If your simple version worked, then it must be something in your larger html code. Could also be a missing quote - `'`/`"` inside an input/checkbox, or some other syntax error.

Comment: the radio button(s) are set up as such `<input type="radio" name="size" value="Small"/>` etc

Comment: Alright. I am not even sure what I changed, or what the issue was. But now it is working... This has been an awful experience, but relieved its over. Thank you everyone for your help.